# Mathematica integrating over set of points to get analytical form of function

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, integration, numerical

I have a following problem - I need to integrate such a  function in Mathematica (I couldn't post an image, so I am writing it in latex form):

G(r)= \int_{0}^{\infty} dq f(q)*q*sin(qr)/r

To obtain function G(r) dependable on r.
Nevertheless I don't know the analytical form of f(q), instead I have set of values of f(q) and for q. So I'd like to make a some kind of numerical integration, but to receive not a value afterwards, but a curve of G(r).

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html

Comment: @JohnDean  If you have more questions about `Mathematica` it will be better if you ask your questions at this site : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com  because it is specifically for `Mathematica` users.

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the analytic form of the function `f[q]` you can do this :

```
Integrate[f[q] q Sin[q r]/r, {q, 0, Infinity}]
```

but in case of knowing only values of `f[q]` you can integrate numerically :

```
G[r_]:= NIntegrate[ f[q] q Sin[q r]/r, {q, 0, Infinity}]
```

Assume e.g.

```
f[q_] := Exp[-q]
Integrate[f[q] q Sin[q r]/r, {q, 0, Infinity}]
```

yields

```
ConditionalExpression[2/(1 + r^2)^2, Abs[Im[r]] < 1]
```

You can make an assumption a priori, e.g. :

```
Assuming[r > 0, Integrate[f[q] q Sin[q r]/r, {q, 0, Infinity}]]
```

yields

```
2/(1 + r^2)^2
```

Assuming `r > 0` you implicitly assume `r` to be real, so `Im[r] == 0`. 
Having the function `G[r]` we can plot the appropriate curve,  defining `f[q]` as above :

```
Plot[ G[r], {r, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. Nevertheless I've some comments - I can't assume any kind of a function, because there is no analytical form of f(q). I know the shape of it as its values are data points from an experiment.

Comment: But I have some other idea - I'd just make a loop for numerical integration for discrete r values and in the end getting discrete form of G(r). But there arises other problem, when I want to make just a numerical integration with my data points, as you have written in second code, I get set of values, not an area under the curve. I don't know why.

Comment: `Assuming` was here only an example how one can refine `ConditionalExpression`. If you know values of `f[q]` you can use `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Maybe use your (q,f(q) known values to create an InterpolatingFunction for f. Then use that in the numeric integration that defines G[r] for numeric r.